# MS Dynamics programming environment

Tags: windows, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to setup MS Dynamics programming/development environment on single PC for self-study purposes for free? How to setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a trial version of CRM Dynamics Online for 30 days. Check [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm.aspx). After set the trial download the [training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23416) and [sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) to study.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but strictly speaking the product itself is its own development environment. Setup info is to be found on the Microsoft Dynamics site:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx